# Are there any wired PC speakers that connect the second speaker either with a 2m+ cable, or with a unpluggable cable?

Tags: cable, speakers

All of the wired (i.e. not Bluetooth, wifi etc) stereo PC speakers that I've come across have ~1m cables between the two speakers that are hard-wired at either end. Therefore the only way to extend the distance between the two is to splice the cables, which with my limited skills is never that durable. What I'm looking for is a speaker set that either has a longer 2m+ cable, or connects to the second speaker with unpluggable cable e.g. with a 3.5mm jack, which I can easily extend with an extension cable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use a "real" speaker system where the speakers have electrical terminals for speaker wire and have to be attached to an amp. Look for "bookshelf" speakers and a stereo amplifier. No reason you can't use this with a normal PC, and it might even sound better than most of those "all in one" desktop speaker systems.

I have a set of these [Micca COVO-S](https://www.miccatron.com/micca-covo-s-concentric-driver-speaker/) speakers attached to a [SMSL SA-36A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B017W13OR0) desktop amplifier. This uses speaker wire that I had to cut to the right length.

You could also look at buying some "active" or "powered" studio monitors for PCs, which are like bookshelf speakers but they have all of the electronics inside the left or right speaker, then some speaker wire runs from the main unit to the other unit.

I would suggest the [Mackie CR3-X](https://mackie.com/intl/products/studio-monitoring/cr-x-series/CR3_X.html) speakers for something that's completely ready to use with a PC and doesn't take up too much desk space.

Comment: Active speakers might need to come with a consumer warning - switch them off before rebooting or unplugging - because the amp on many of them is always at full volume. I have a pair of active studio monitors than can nearly take your face off if you forget. They're 400W too… damned loud. ;)

Comment: Looks like there is some marketing terminology confusion around this. "Active" usually means the speaker has its own amplifier that amplifies from line level, but these ones are meant to plug into RCAs or 3.5mm jacks and **always** have volume control because line level is standardized so the only volume control possible is in the amp. You just set the volume knob and don't need to worry about them going louder than expected. Both solutions I linked definitely don't need the loudness warning.

Comment: I suspect that those always 100% volume "studio monitors" used in real recording studio and live setups are using XLR inputs and can't directly plug into a PC anyways. They will need something in-between like a mixer, which has its own volume control too.

Comment: Thanks, went with your second suggestion of studio monitors, specifically PreSonus Eris E3.5 which is a competitor of the CR3-X. They do exactly what I want in terms of having a separate cable connecting the speakers and if need be that cable can be replaced with an even longer one.